# How to mutiple data to nested serializer in django restframework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have defined a serializer that has two nested serializers as shown below. How do I pass the multiple data to it. I have added my attempted approach.

```
class NameSlugProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    product = ProductSerializer(read_only=True)
    product_options = ProductOptionSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_product(request, name_slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, name_slug=name_slug)
    product_options = ProductOption.objects.filter(product=product)
    //how do i pass the data
    serializer = NameSlugProductSerializer(product, product_options)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try instantiating the serilalizer following way:

```
serializer = NameSlugProductSerializer(instance={"product": product, "product_options": product_options})
```

Comment: I appreciate it